# How to use an ODBC connection to an Access .mdb file in a .NRY Core 3.0 app

Tags: ms-access, .net-core, odbc

I have a .NRY Standard 2.0 Project with a class library where I use the System.DataODBC (installed as Nuget Package) to connect to an Access mdb file.
I then wrote a .Net Framework 4.7.2 console app to test the library and that works as expected. I then wrote a .Net Core 3.0 console app, because the app that in the end will be using the library is a .Net Core app. But this didn't work I get this error:

> ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

But I then tried to compile the solution with "x86" instead of "Any CPU" - And that works. I then think it must have something to do with the ODBC driver for 32 of 64 bit?

To be clear I haven't configured any ODBC driver with ODBC admin (odbcad32.exe). I can now run the core Console App in Visual Studio and stand-alone.

But when I put the Core Console app on another machine (a clean install Windows 10 pro in a VM) it still won't work.

What do I have to do/install in the VM machine to get it up running?

Answer (score 1):

If you use mdb (the older legacy JET engine), then you  can connect on any machine since a copy of the JET database is shipped with each copy of windows. And YES, you will have to force  your project to x32 (x86) since the JET data engnie is only available in x32 versions.

If you use ACE, then you are using the  newer ACE data engine which is require if you use the Access 2007 and later format (so for accDB files, you MUST use ACE).

Of course like any drivers or software, if you going to deploy to additional machines, then you have to ensure  that ACE is installed. As a general rule, you then have to (should) install the access connectivity components. eg this one:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920

Keep in mind that there are two versions of the above. A x64 bit version, and a x32 bit version. You want to continue to FORCE you .net project to x32 or x64, since you can't leave this choice to the wind.
So, you have to include the above install as part of your installer, or simply provide a copy, or have users download + install.

The only way to eliminate the need for above is to go with JET, but that may not be a possible choice for you, and you are restricted to mdb files, and can't use accDB files with JET.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick answer.

But I found that to run a .Net core app using the System.Data.ODBC the app heve to be compiled for x86 CPU and the server where the app is installed needs to have the .Net Core runtime 32-bit version installed.

Comment: Well that assumes you using x32 ACE drivers. If you used x64  ACE, then of course you install x64 bit versions of your software. If you use .net framework, then by default the .net framework (I think up to version 4 or 4.5 is installed by default on recent versions of windows - including servers).